# Enumerating nested item with skips

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem, nesting

I need to do some nested  numbering of items, but with skips. I can skip outer numbering, but similar method is not working with inner numbering. I have the code below, where the numbering starts from 2, as desired, but the inner numbering does not start from (e). How would I go about achieving this.

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \setcounter{enumi}{1}
    \item
    \begin{enumerate}
        \setcounter{enumi}{4}       
        \item My answer to 2e.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

**Note**: *The need for doing this arises for a redo of some homework questions*.

Comment: You want to adjust `\enumii`, `\enumiii` etc as you go deeper.

Comment: The second counter is enumii with two i at the end.

Comment: Works great, I could have never imagined that myself :). Please add that as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's much easier with »[enumitem](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem)«.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}[start=2]
    \item
    \begin{enumerate}[start=5]
      \item My answer to 2e.
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

The problem is the counter you are using. `enumi` is for the first level, for the second level you have to use `enumii`, third would be `enumiii`. So your code should be as below:

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \setcounter{enumi}{1}
    \item
    \begin{enumerate}
        \setcounter{enumii}{4}       
        \item My answer to 2e.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```